# Relationships and channel images

Tags: relationships, channel-images

I'm trying to get channel images to show within a ee relationship. All the title and links show correctly, but the images are not showing at all.

Running EE 3.5.7 and channel images 6.0.3

I'm using the following code:

```
<aside class="widget latest-post-widget">
<h4>Editors Picks</h4>
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="cria_picks" limit="3"}
{cria_editors_picks}
<li class="media">
<div class="media-left">
<a href="{cria_editors_picks:url_title_path='criaviews/article'}" class="popular-img">
{exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{cria_editors_picks:entry_id}"}
<img src="{image:url:medium}" style="width: 103px; height:76px;" alt="">
{/exp:channel_images:images}
</a>
</div>
<div class="latest-post-content">
<h2><a href="{cria_editors_picks:url_title_path='criaviews/article/'}">
{cria_editors_picks:title}
</a></h2>
<p><time datetime="{cria_editors_picks:entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i"}" pubdate class="updated">{date_heading}{cria_editors_picks:entry_date format="%d %F %Y"}{/date_heading}</time></p>
</div>
</li>
{/cria_editors_picks}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
</aside>
```

Not sure what I'm missing. I'm using this code as an embed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that {cria_editors_picks:entry_id} is a valid ID?
You can also try 
`{cria_editors_picks} YOUR CODE
    {embed"YOUR-FILE" entry_id="{cria_editors_picks:entry_id}"}
    MORE CODE
{/cria_editors_picks}`

Then in YOUR-FILE

```
JUST TO TEST -> THE ID IS : {embed:entry_id} <br>
{exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}
    <img src="{image:url:medium}" style="width: 103px; height:76px;" alt="">
{/exp:channel_images:images}
```